# Exogeneity of volatility shocks in Local projection model

Tags: garch, projection, volatility, exogeneity

I want to estimate the impact of volatility shocks on cross-assets spillovers. I have series of spillovers, and I want to use a Local Projection model, and the volatility of some financial assets representing the shocks, my goal is to estimate the following model:

$S_{i,t+H} = a_0 + \delta_1 \sigma_{i,t} + \delta_2 X_t+\varepsilon_{i,t} $

Where $S_{i,t+H}$ is the cross-asset spillover, $\sigma_{i,t}$ is the volatility and $X_t$ are control variables.

Is it okay to estimate such a model? $S$ and $\sigma$ are endogeneous, so I've estimated another equation instead:
$S_{i,t+H} = a_0 + \delta_1 \sigma_{i,t-1} + \delta_2 X_t+\varepsilon_{i,t} $

in which the volatility is lagged to tackle endogeneity, but I'm not sure that this is properly done (is it enough?).

In addition, it is not (here) a "shock" on volatility that is used. Can I do it still?

I've figured that I can estimate a volatility shock following [Bloom (2009)](https://pages.stern.nyu.edu/%7Edbackus/GE_asset_pricing/Bloom%20uncer%20shocks%20Ec%2009.pdf) by taking 1.65 standard deviation above the mean (and it works just fine) but the results are the same as the ones with the series of volatility without any shock identification.

So, overall: can a series, without transformation, be used as a "shock" variable in a LP model; is it enough to take the first lag of the endogeneous variable to tackle endogeneity in a panel model?

**References**

- Bloom, N. (2009). [The impact of uncertainty shocks.](https://pages.stern.nyu.edu/%7Edbackus/GE_asset_pricing/Bloom%20uncer%20shocks%20Ec%2009.pdf) *Econometrica, 77*(3), 623-685.

Comment: What do you mean by *the conditional volatility <...> must be exogeneous to the innovations of others variables*. Why must it? Which of the models require or imply that?

Comment: I've read in some papers (I can look for them if needed) that the volatility estimated in a multivariate GARCH can be viewed as exogeneous as it is conditional to the innovations in others variables too. If I do understand it well - which is probable that I don't - it would mean that this series is exogeneous to the others variables (if there is no common factor I mean), and to their innovations

Comment: Exogenous with respect to what? In a multivariate GARCH model, the conditional variance matrix is the dependent variable, so it is endogenous by definition.

Comment: I though that, as the model takes in account the influence of the other variables, the measured volatility would be independent of those variables as it withdraw this interaction.

Comment: If $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+u$, then $\hat y=\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x$ is a function of $x$, so the measured value $\hat y$ is definitely not independent of $x$. The same applies to GARCH.

Comment: So I can't use the measured volatility as an exogeneous shock per se. Do you think that using the lagged value would be sufficient ? Is there a statistical test to help this choice ?

Comment: Exogenous shock to what? In what context? Lagged value of what, in what context?

Comment: I'll add more context in the above question. I have series of cross-asset spillovers that I want to explain with relative volatility of each asset. However, volatility (shocks) isn't exogeneous to spillovers, so I was looking for a method to model this relationship in the best way

Comment: I am confused. You may want to spell out your situation in more detail and in a logical sequence by editing the post, otherwise it is a bit hard to keep track.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question with much more details, hope it's enough (and I've modified the question as the conditional volatility measured in a GARCH is clearly not exogeneous !)

Comment: How do you define a cross-asset spillover? How do you define a volatility shock? (Define, not estimate. Once we get the definitions, we can talk about estimation.)

Comment: Spillovers occurs when an idiosyncratic shock in one asset is transmitted to another (through the portfolio rebalancing channel mainly). A volatility shock is a significant shift of an asset volatility. I use the Diebold-Yilmaz (2012) methodology to estimate the cross-assets spillovers, and the volatility shock is estimated, as in Bloom (2009) !

Comment: Could you edit the main post to include a full reference for Bloom (2009)?

Comment: Is there a lag between $S_{i,t+H}$ and $\sigma_{i,t}$? Just by looking at the time indices, it looks like there is. Then the regressors are predetermined w.r.t. the regressand, and you do not have to worry about endogeneity.

Comment: I edited the reference. There is a lag between $S_{i,t+H}$ and $\sigma_i,t$, but I didn't know if it was enough to ensure exogeneity !

Comment: In time series, you may not have exogeneity, but you can get away with predetermined regressors. E.g. in a model $y_t=\varphi_1 y_{t-1}+u_t$, the regressor is endogenous (it is a random variable from the same process as the regressand) but it is predetermined, so we do not get the usual problems caused by endogeneity.

Comment: Note: a link is not a reference. Links go dead, and then the incomplete reference quite often becomes useless. I have included a proper reference now.